# Shrink data MDF file on server running on low disk space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, shrink

Before proceeding, I know the cons of doing this and have read many questions on same. But since we are here on urgent need and adding disk would take over a couple of days and the DB in question being not that critical, so is there a way I can release the unused space from database.

Below screenshot says unused space as 36 GB, but when I execute sp_spaceused it says unused as some 400 MB but unallocated much more.

[image]

I waited for almost 4 hours, trying to shrink in chunks, but not even a single MB got shrinked.

Is there a way this can be done or how can I manage the unallocated space?

Please advise.

Comment: It may help to visually look at this information in SQL Server Management Studio by right-clicking on the database, going to Reports, then Standard Reports, and finally Disk Usage. How are you trying to shrink the file?

Comment: Did you attempt ShrinkDB or ShrinkFile?

Comment: Please post the exact shrink command that you executed.

Comment: Does your database have a lot of LOB data? LOB data can significantly slow down a shrink operation. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-lob-data-makes-shrink-run-slooooowly-t-sql-tuesday-006/

Comment: @SeanGallardy, Shrink file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sp_spaceused` provides 2 sets of the data:
- DB Size + Unallocated space - These numbers include BOTH: Data and log file;
- Total statistics of RESERVED space for all objects within the database;

I bet your 36 GB of free space are in the Log file.

For real numbers use following query:

```
SELECT 
    f.file_id as "File Id",
    f.physical_name as "Physical Name",
    CAST(CAST(ROUND(f.Size/128.,3) as DECIMAL(16,3)) as VARCHAR(16)) AS SizeMB,
    CAST(CAST(ROUND(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.,3) as DECIMAL(16,3)) as VARCHAR(16)) AS UsedSpaceMB,
    RIGHT('  ' + CAST(CAST((1 - FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed') * 1./ f.size) * 100 as DECIMAL(5,2)) as VARCHAR(6)),6) AS FreeSpacePrc
    ,  CASE f.file_id WHEN 2 THEN 'Log File' ELSE IsNull(g.name,'N/A') END as [File Group]
FROM sys.database_files as f with (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups as g with (nolock) ON f.data_space_id = g.data_space_id
```

Might happen you still have some opened transactions, which hold you from shrinking individual files. See who hols them, close them. Reboot server if necessary. Shrink individual files while nobody accessing the database. switch it temporarily to Single User if necessary:

```
ALTER DATABASE <Your database> SET SINGLE_USER
```

Comment: File Id Physical Name SizeMB UsedSpaceMB FreeSpacePrc File Group
1 D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\ABC.mdf 63384.625 26452.438  58.27 PRIMARY
2 L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ABC_1.ldf 577.000 31.016  94.62 Log File

Comment: As you can see, you have more than 30Gb in your Log file and surprisingly 26Gb in the data file. Will add some info to the answer right now.

Comment: ,I believe its 30MB. I am not sure how you calculated that as 30 GB on log file. Out of 63 GB on data file there is only 26 used and rest free

Comment: My fault. It looks like my bet was wrong. Missed the dot. You'd better provided results within a question. Also, provide commands you've used to shrink individual files.